# Dont know how to test an API I wrote :|

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api

I am learning how to write APIs in Rails. I managed to write an API to create an object. However, I'm facing issues on how to invoke it.

1. Routes.rb

   namespace :api do
       namespace :v1 do 
         resources :company_donations
       end 
     end
2. App/Controllers/Api/v1/Company_donation_controller has create method which requires 3 objects to be passed token, api_key and an object called donation with variables amount and comment.
3. Now I want to test my own API. How do I call this post API from a rake task? Use open-uri? How do I invoke following code?

post "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/company_donations.json", :token => "HusGbrnhi2s3EmUB7fHH",
                        :api_key => "f70aa490-dc2a-012e-da4e-442c03154814",
                        :donation => {
                          :amount => 101,
                          :comment => "Ordered 2 books"
                        }

Comment: May I suggest some shorter meta-syntactic values? "foo" and "bar" are quite popular...

Comment: Found a Nestful.post library that makes the call but I think the parameters are not getting passed. My new call is in next comment. Please advise

Comment: puts Nestful.post "http://localhost:3000/ api/v1/company_donations.json? token=foo &api_key=bar &donation{&amount=101&comment=Ordered}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologise for answering my own question. I eventually used - Nestful.post library helped.